# Sparql on Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I go to Virtuoso Conductor (http://localhost:8890/conductor)>Linked Data>Quad Store Upload and then i upload a ttl file with 500 rows.
However when i go to "http://localhost:8890/sparql" and i query:

```
"SELECT *   from       <http://localhost:8890/DAV>   WHERE {?s ?p ?o} "
```

It returns only the first 25 results.
[image]
Do you know why?

Comment: check your `virtuoso.ini` file, check `ResultSetMaxRows` param, maybe you have it set to 25?

Comment: and why `FROM http://localhost:8890/DAV`? Did you load it into this graph?

Comment: Your screenshot shows only one column, but it should show three, for your `SELECT`. You may find the results interesting, if you query `SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}` and `SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o} }`...

Comment: Remove "from  <http://localhost:8890/DAV>" and retry ?

Comment: Other possibilities include invalid data in the original file (so only 25, or only the first 25, lines may have been loaded into the quad store)... With no further info from you, no-one can help you.